# Photovoltaic Device and Photon Absorption

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, electric-circuits

When dealing with a photodiode photons with lower energy (such as red light) penetrate deeper then a photon with higher energy (such as blue light). The responsivity of the photodiode has a lower limit given by the band gap energy (Eg) which must be exceeded by the energy of the photon. The upper limit is given by the penetration depth.

Intuitively I would think that when you exceed the energy of the band gap significantly the high energy photon would pass straight through the photodiode similar to how an X-ray works. Why is this not the case?

Comment: Yet x-ray detectors work just fine...